# Failed to retrieve directory listing on Amazon workspace

Tags: ftp, sftp, winscp, filezilla, amazon-workspaces

I have recently moved from remote desktop (pval) to amazon workspaces and while using filezilla on amazon workspace i am not able to retrieve directory listing from a specific client's ftp. not sure but i think it is either stemming from filezilla configuration difference or a performance drop causing filezilla to time out but i have also tried using 9999 or 0 to disable timeout and tried enabling ICMP as well.

port : 22,
SFTP connection,
number of files in root folder: 102918

any idea why is it not working on amazon workspace ?

PVAL

[image]

Amazon workspace

[image]

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its is because of large number of files which is clogging the directory, try to archive the files